# Handling the data portion of a jQuery AJAX call to WCF REST service

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, wcf, rest

Fairly new to jQuery, I have a .ajax call going to a WCF RESTful service and my Uri template on the operation contract is the following:

```
UriTemplate = "/{appName}/{custCode}/{custUserName}/counter"
```

My problem is, I have a what is either going to be XML or JSON that I want to save to a database via the service and I'm confused how to get the service to receive the payload without having it as a variable in the Url.

My AJAX call looks like this so far:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: ‘{../{appName}/{custCode}/{custUserName}/counter}’
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, I think that you're asking how to send data to that server via ajax.

What you need to do is specify what the data is and add it to the 'data' setting in your ajax request.

So

```
var myData = "whatever your data is";
$.ajax({
    type="POST",
    url: ‘{../{appName}/{custCode}/{custUserName}/counter}’,
    data: myData
 })
```

You can also specify what to do with the response you get, perhaps letting the user know his/her data was saved or some such.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ is the list of all settings.

Comment: Will that not send myData in the Url along with "/{appName}/{custCode}/{custUserName}/counter"?

Comment: It will not, because you have set the type to "POST". If you set the type to "GET", then it will send the data in the URL.

This primarily has to do with how the page you're hitting with your AJAX call handles its data.

When using POST, your request sends the data in the POST array. This is usually accessed via the POST superglobal. For example, in PHP, to grab email data from a form I've submitted with POST, I would write

    $email = $_POST[email];

The service that you're making an AJAX call to likely defines how you should format the data you are sending.